# R filter or subset for finding a specific repeat count for data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I want to use  filter or subset  from dplyr  that will give a new dataframe only with rows in which for the selected column the value is counted exactly 2 times in the original data.frame
I try this:

```
df2 <-
df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>%   mutate(duplicate = n()) %>% 
  filter(duplicate == 2)
```

and this

```
df2 <- subset(df,duplicated(x))
```

but neither option works

Answer (score 1):

In the group_by, just use the unquoted column name. Also, we don't need to create a column in `mutate` before `filter`ing.  It can be directly done on the fly in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(x) %>%
   filter(n() ==2) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's a big dataframe with many rows. Don't I have to add some for loop to make it check for all rows?

Comment: @Sylvie you don't need any for loop here. if the 'x' column values doesn't have any leading/lagging spaces, it gives the correct count with `n()` after grouping (also assuming it is not a float where precision matters)

Comment: @Sylvie I would also request that  in the future when you post questions, it is better to post with a small reproducible example in the question preferably with `dput` as `dput` gives the correct structure of your data.  This would help others in debugging the issue faster. ie. `dput(head(df, 20))` returns the structure of first 20 rows

Comment: Thank you again, I have 20 columns (V1, ...,, V20)
and I want the new data.frame to contain only those rows for which the values appear exactly 2 times in the V13 column in the original data.frame

Comment: @Sylvie, then you should be `df %>% group_by(V17) %>% filter(n() == 2) %>% ungroup`